# How to make graph with every row included seperately

Tags: excel, vba

How to make a VBA script for it to include all rows to the - graph. the graph is scattered, so I can't add a range of rows, need to have a For argument and to include every rows with X and Y values accordingly.

I am bad at programming, so tried some macros but it didn't help.

```
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("page1")
    For i = 4 To 155
        For k = 1 To 155    
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select

            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(k).Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(k).XValues = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(k).Values = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
            k = k + 1
            i = i + 1
        Next k
    Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: You can set a range of cells as a `Series.Collection`. Loop through your rows and add them accordingly.

Comment: Can you give an example/indication of what your input data looks like?